# Disable the current clicked button with ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I want to disable the button that is currently clicked on the page but I can't make it happen. Here is my last try that still did not work. I tried to return a value from the Ajax page that is serverii and match it with the current ID to show the disable but it did not work.

**php:**

```
    <?php
       if (isset($_GET['movie'])) {
        
       
       $id=$_GET['movie'];
$get = $data->show(" SELECT * FROM servers WHERE movie_id='$id' ORDER BY server_id DESC");
foreach ($get as $row) {
 $id=$row['server_id'];
 $name=$row['server_name'];
 $link=$row['link'];
?>
       <button type="button" id="btn" value="<?php $id ?>" class="btn btn-warning m-2 p-2 <?php if($id==$serverii) echo 'disabled'?>" onclick="getmovie(<?php echo $id ?>)" > <?php echo "$name"; ?> </button>
        <?php }} ?>
```

**Ajax:**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
         function getmovie(serverid){
    
            $.ajax({
    
            url:"../../control/operation/view_movie.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{serverid:serverid},
            success:function(data)
                {
    
                    $("#show").html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    
        </script>
```

**view_movie.php page:**

```
      if (isset($_POST['serverid'])) {
        
    
        $id=$_POST['serverid'];
        $getuser = $data->getdata("SELECT * FROM servers WHERE server_id='$id'");
        $link=$getuser['link'];
        $name=$getuser['film_name'];
        $serverii=$getuser['server_id'];
      
         ?>
      <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="<?php echo $link ?>" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    
    <?php } ?>
```

Anyone know an easy way to do that? I just want a sign that tells the user that he is on that server currently. Change color or something that is different from other buttons.

Comment: you need to `echo` the id in the html button

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius i tried that now i echo it in the value but still did not work

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius no it is bootstrap class it works fine for other stuff i think i have a problem in my condition

Comment: You have not specified what database you are using or which api (mysql,mysqli or PDO ) but the above SQL is vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius i am using mysqli OOP classes i secured all of them to prevent sql injections

Comment: `movie_id='$id'` takes unsanitised user input - thus vulnerable!

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius i will fix that thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a little alteration to the button code and how the javascript function `getmovie` operates. Rather than hardcoding the ID as a parameter of the function you can refer to the button from within the javascript function using `this` and from that obtain the ID which is the `value` for the button.

I made note below about the need for using a prepared statement and also passed comment to that effect so the sql below is "as was"

```
<?php
    if ( isset( $_GET['movie'] ) ) {
        /*
            This really should be using a prepared statement!!!
        */
        $id = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'movie', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
        $get = $data->show("SELECT 
                                `server_id`,
                                `server_name`,
                                `link` 
                            FROM `servers` 
                            WHERE `movie_id`='$id' 
                            ORDER BY server_id DESC");
        
        
        
        
        foreach( $get as $row ) {
            $id=$row['server_id'];
            $name=$row['server_name'];
            $link=$row['link'];
?>
        <!-- 
        
            "echo" the ID in the value and modify function 
            call to accept `event` as the single argument.
            
            There is no specific need for the ID as this 
            would be duplicated in the loop and we can refer
            to button in Javascript using `this`
            
        -->
        <button type='button' value='<?php echo $id; ?>' class='btn btn-warning m-2 p-2 <?php if( $id==$serverii ) echo 'disabled'; ?>' onclick='getmovie( event );'>
            <?php echo $name; ?>
        </button>
<?php 
        }
    }
?>






<script>

    function getmovie( e ){
        //perhaps not strictly required for a regular button...
        e.preventDefault();
        
        //disable the button.
        e.target.disabled=true;
        
        $.ajax({
            url:'../../control/operation/view_movie.php',
            method:'POST',
            data:{ 'serverid':e.target.value },
            success:function( data ){
                $('#show').html( data );
            },
            error:function( err ){
                alert( err )
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

I put together a quick demo

```
<?php

    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
    
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        /* random nonsense as response... */
        $_POST['date']=date(DATE_ATOM);
        $_POST['ip']=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        exit(json_encode($_POST));
    }
    
    
    
    $rs=array(
        array( 'server_id'=>'pdc', 'server_name'=>'corp-dc-01', 'link'=>'\\example.com\corp-dc-01' ),
        array( 'server_id'=>'adfs', 'server_name'=>'corp-adfs-01', 'link'=>'\\example.com\corp-adfs-01' ),
        array( 'server_id'=>'file', 'server_name'=>'corp-fs-01', 'link'=>'\\example.com\corp-fs-01' ),
        array( 'server_id'=>'bdc', 'server_name'=>'corp-dc-02', 'link'=>'\\example.com\corp-dc-02' ),
        array( 'server_id'=>'adfs-2', 'server_name'=>'corp-adfs-02', 'link'=>'\\example.com\corp-adfs-02' ),
        array( 'server_id'=>'file-2', 'server_name'=>'corp-fs-02', 'link'=>'\\example.com\corp-fs-02' )
    );
    
    # to emulate a chosen server... selected at random
    $serverii=$rs[mt_rand(0,count($rs)-1)]['server_id'];
    
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
        <script src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js'></script>
        <script>
            function getmovie( e ){
                e.preventDefault();
                e.target.disabled=true;

                $.ajax({
                    url:location.href,  //'../../control/operation/view_movie.php'
                    method:'POST',
                    data:{
                        'serverid':e.target.value,
                        'link':e.target.dataset.link,
                        name:e.target.innerText
                    },
                    success:function( data ){
                        $('#show').html( data );
                    },
                    error:function( err ){
                        alert( err )
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
        <style>
            button{padding:1rem;margin:1rem;}
            .disabled{color:red;}
            :disabled{background:red;color:white}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method='post'>
            <div id='show'></div>
            <?php
            
                printf( '<h1>Active:%s</h1>',$serverii );
            
            
                foreach( $rs as $svr ){
                    $id=$svr['server_id'];
                    $name=$svr['server_name'];
                    $link=$svr['link'];
                    $disabled=$id==$serverii ? 'disabled' : '';
                    
                    printf(
                        '<button type="button" value="%s" data-link="%s" class="btn btn-warning m-2 p-2 %s" onclick="getmovie( event );">
                            %s
                        </button>',
                        $id,
                        $link,
                        $disabled,
                        $name
                    );
                }
            ?>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for the help i got the idea but for some reason the view_movie page is not showing up i will try to fix that maybe there is problem on passing the data thanks again

Comment: check the browser console - look at the network traffic and any errors.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: e.preventDefault is not a function
    at getmovie (viewmovie.php?movie=2:306)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (viewmovie.php?movie=2:348)
    at e (jquery.min.js:2)
    at t (jquery.min.js:2)`
i get this im still trying to fix it

Comment: did you modify the html button as in the above? `onclick='getmovie( event );'`

Comment: apologies: just tested this and to my shame found i mislead you a little. use `e.target` rather than `this` - see edited version

Comment: thanks it worked fine but when i click on any button it will be disabled for ever i tried to fix it with this  `$( ".btn" ).click(function() {  e.target.disabled=false;});` 
when the page loads thanks again

Comment: I believed that you wanted to disable the button? It will not be disabled when the page is loaded again.

Comment: i wanted the user to know which server he is currently using by disabling the current button and when he click on another one the last one be enable again and the clicked one be disabled

Answer (score 1):

Call on click: `$("#btn").prop('disabled', true);`

Comment: i tried that it worked for the last button i mean by that the last id it will be disabled

Comment: OK if you need, you can use their class for recognize all button: `$(".btn").prop('disabled', true);`

Comment: But you need check all click on page: `$(".btn").click(function() {
 $(this).prop('disabled', true);
)};`

Comment: that works thanks can you tell me how to enable the other old button when i click a new button i want the user to know what button he currently on

Comment: It will be easiest if you don’t mind unlocking all the buttons on the page. First you open all buttons `$(".btn").prop('disabled', false);` then close specific one `$(this).prop('disabled', true);`